# Rendering speed of child views

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, promise, backbone-views

I have a child view that is added to the front page of a newspaper. It displays movie listings for certain days of the week.

It works, but there is a delay...its the last item to visibly appear on a page.

The movies are not part of the model that represents a day.

So it must fetch a Movie collection per for each of these child views.

Here is how I have it set up.

As I said it works, I am just looking for ideas on how to increase the speed at which the MovieViews are loaded on screen:

```
initialize: function (args) {
   this.movies = new MovieCollection();
   this.promise = this.fetchMovies(this.model.id);
},

render: function () {

        this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
        this.renderMovies(this.$('.movieListing'));

  renderMovies: function (el) {
        var self = this;
        $.when(self.promise).done(function() {
            var view = new MovieView({
                model: self.movies,
                el: el
            });

            if (self.movies.length > 0) {
                view.render();
            }
        });
    },

    fetchMovies: function (id) {
        return this.movies.fetch({ url: '/api/theaters/' + id+ '/movies' });
    }
});
```

Thanks!

Comment: One way to go about is bootstrap the data to the page. When the page loads, have a subset of data ( if batching is already present) and avoid making the API page when the page loads. OR  fix the query which pulls the data which is the root cause.

Comment: @Sushanth-- is 100% spot on. If this data is on a landing page, then use the power and near-zero-latency of the server-side to bootstrap the data.

Comment: What does that mean? Bootstrap the data server side? Thanks

Comment: I believe they are suggesting that your landing page is served with the movie listings section pre-rendered. In other words, render that part of the page on the server side so that it gets displayed straight away without the need for a fetch request to get the data.